Запуск objcopy для всех исполняемых файлов
кароч, использую я специфичный компилятор, он требует после линковки запускать objcopy
как-то так:
mytoolchain-gcc main.c -o main.o
mytoolchain-ld main.o -o main.exe
mytoolchain-objcopy main.exe -O binary

так вот для cmake я нащел только так:
add_executable(Example Example.c)
add_custom_command(
    TARGET Example POST_BUILD
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_OBJCOPY} ARGS Example.exe -O binary
    COMMENT "objcpy"
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}
)

Но создавать для каждого бинарника команду как то запарно. Можно ли сделать так чтоб не писать add_custom_command ручками?
